# Verify Gauss’s Divergence Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have this assignment which we have not tackled and am getting mixed up in the divergence theorem tutorials like this one http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/diverg/diverg.html

`Verify Gauss’s Divergence Theorem for F= 4 xiˆ− 2y jˆ+ zkˆ  over the region bounded by ρ = 4, z = −2, and z = 2.`

Help me get it solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that on the contrary:

$$\iint \vec{F}\, \vec{dS} = \iiint \operatorname{div} \vec{F}\, dV$$

Edit -  reneval:

$$S = S_1 \cup  S_2 \cup S_3$$

$S_1=$ part of a cylindrical surface $\varrho = 4 \equiv x^2+y^2=16\,, z  \in \langle-2,2\rangle$

$$S_2 = \operatorname{cover} \varrho \le 4\,, z=2\,;   S_3 = \operatorname{bottom} \varrho \le 4\,, z=-2$$

$$\iint_S \vec{F}\, \vec{dS}=\iint_{S_1} \vec{F}\, \vec{dS}+\iint_{S_2} \vec{F}\, \vec{dS}+\iint_{S_3} \vec{F}\, \vec{dS}$$

$\underline{1.\,  S1:}\,  \vec{n}=$ unit outer normal vector

$$\iint_{S_1} \vec{F}\, \vec{dS}=\iint_{S_1} \vec{F}\cdot \vec{n}\, dS,\text{ substitution:} x = 4\cos t\,, y = 4\sin t,\, z = z$$

$$\Rightarrow n=(\cos t,\sin t,0)\,, F=(16\cos t,32\sin^2t,z^2)\,, \vec{F}\cdot \vec{n}=(16\cos^2t+32\sin^2t+ 0),\, dS = 4\,dt\,dz $$

$$\Rightarrow\, =32\int_{-2}^{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi}(2\cos^2t+4\sin^3t)\,dt\,dz= \cdots = 256\pi$$

$\underline{2. S2,S3:}\,  \vec{n_2}=(0,0,1)\, \vec{n_2}=(0,0,-1)$ unit outer normal vectors

A similar calculation is determined that $\iint_{S_1}+\iint_{S_2}=0$

so $\underline{\iint \vec{F}\, \vec{dS} = 256\pi}$

$\underline{3.}$

$\operatorname{div} \vec{F} = 4 + 4y + 2z$

$$\underline{\iiint \operatorname{div} \vec{F}\, dV}=\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-4}^{4}\int_{_{-\sqrt{16-x^2}}}^{^{\sqrt{16-x^2}}}(4 + 4y + 2z)\,dy\,dx\,dz=\cdots =\underline{256\pi}$$

Comment: then what next from there?

Comment: To look at this site is to marvel at the seemingly incredible fact that people are able to acquire such phenomenal degrees of unskillfulness at MathJax.  I think I've cleaned up most of it.  I confess to suspecting that lots of people who post here do not refer to things like LaTeX manuals as the occasion arises.

Comment: @georg : In particular, could you write $z\in\langle -2,2\rangle$ instead of $z\,\epsilon\,<-2,2>$, and $\cos t$ instead of $cos t$, and $(\cdots)\,dy\,dx\,dz$ instead of $(\cdots)dy dx dz$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Thanks for the instructions. I will try.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the he help

Answer (score 0):

Your field is $F(x,y,z) = (4x,2y^2,z^2)$? And when you say $\rho = 2$, that means you have to do your integral in spherical coordenates??

Comment: Check the image I have added

Comment: Well, what I would do is this:

First, calculate $div\,F = \dfrac{{\partial}F}{{\partial}x} + \dfrac{{\partial}F}{{\partial}y} + \dfrac{{\partial}F}{{\partial}z} = 4 + 4y + 2z$. Then, I calculate

$$ \int\int\int_S\,div\,F = \int_{-2}^2\,\int_0^{2\pi}\,\int_0^4\,(4+4(4\cos\,{\theta}+2z)\,d{\rho}\,d{\theta}\,dz $$

i.e., I made the integral in polar coordenates. Doing those integrals you can find your answer.

I except this helps you.

Comment: why are you using 4cosθ?